# Reference request: $p$-adic modular forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, modular-forms

Are there any introductory texts about $p$-adic modular forms? You can assume a basic knowledge of the theory of classical modular forms. I am aware of the article by Serre, by I was wondering if there exists something with a modern approach/style.

Comment: I was under the opinion that most of Serre's work is a modern approach/style. I'd have to check my copy to make sure, but his book a course in arithmetic seems extremely likely to contain said info, though I'm not sure it's an introductory book. What sort of level do you mean as introductory? suitable for undergrads, phd students, researchers?

Comment: It's probably not modern, but there is Fernando Quadros Gouvea _Arithmetic of p-adic Modular Forms_, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg (1988).

Comment: @N8tron I didn't refer to "A course in arithmetic" since it does not contain any reference about $p$-adic modular forms, just the classical ones. I referred to a paper of Serre. Anyway even for that I wouldn't indicate "A course in Arithmetic" as modern. For classical modular forms the styles of Diamond and Koblitz are definitely more gentle. I mean suitable for master/PhD's students.

Comment: @Watson Thank you for your reference. Well, the problem with that text is that it seems to require a serious background in other areas like elliptic curves, schemes and moduli spaces. I hoped in something more introductory and gentle. Exactly like the text of Gouvea himself about $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: @Blacksmith : I completely agree with you! [Here is another reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=J122DAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false) that might be interesting. If you find any other nice source, please let me know :-)

Comment: There are some [detailed notes by Calegari](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2013/2013CalegariLectureNotes.pdf). Here is a [brief introduction](https://wstein.org/edu/2011/581g/final/spicer-p-adic_modular_forms.pdf). One problem: Serre's approach to $p$-adic modular forms ($p$-adic modular forms as $p$-adic limits of classical ones) is *not* the modern approach. The modern approach views $p$-adic modular forms as sections of line bundles on modular curves, and does require at least a basic knowledge of elliptic curves and moduli spaces.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you Mathmo. I didn't know about the main differences between the old and the modern approach. I thought the modern approach started with the paper by Serre and that it proceded in that direction.

Comment: [The list here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~fcale/AWS.html) might be useful.